# OpenGL: two spheres in single vertex buffer

Tags: java, opengl, lwjgl, vbo

(Question is at bottom)Im learning opengl(using lwjgl) and done some drawing of flat shape through sending buffers. Now I need to draw many spheres in single buffer. In my last question, I was advised to use geometry instancing but I dont know how to use any shader language in java yet so I'm trying to make multiple objects in single buffer just like in the examples.

What I tried to generate two spheres by QUAD_STRIP style(using lwjgl's own GLU.Sphere() function to fill the buffers):

```
n=c1*(c2+1);
        float rr=(float) Math.random();
        float gg=(float) Math.random();
        float bb=(float) Math.random();
        float aa=(float) Math.random();

        positions = new float[c1 * (c2+1) * 3*2 *2];
        normals = new float[c1 * (c2+1) * 3*2 *2];
        colors = new float[c1 * (c2+1) * 4*2 *2];
        int counter=0;
        float drho = 3.141593F / 32.0f;
        float dtheta = 6.283186F / 32.0f;
        float ds = 1.0F / 32.0f;
        float dt = 1.0F / 32.0f;
        float t = 1.0F;

        /*first sphere*/
        for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
            float rho = i * drho;

            float s = 0.0F;
            for (int j = 0; j <= 32; j++) {
              float theta = j == 32 ? 0.0F : j * dtheta;
              float x = (float) (-Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(rho));
              float y = (float) (Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(rho));
              float z = (float) (1.0f * Math.cos(rho));           

              normals[counter*3+0]=x*1.0f;normals[counter*3+1]=y*1.0f;normalscounter*3+2]=z*1.0f;

              colors[counter*4+0]=rr;colors[counter*4+1]=gg;colors[counter*4+2]=bb;colors[counter*4+3]=1.0f/*aa*/;  

              positions[counter*3+0]=x*r;positions[counter*3+1]=y*r;positions[counter*3+2]=z*r;
              counter++;
              x = (float) (-Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(rho + drho));
              y = (float) (Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(rho + drho));
              z = (float) (1.0f * Math.cos(rho + drho));

              normals[counter*3+0]=x*1.0f;normals[counter*3+1]=y*1.0f;normals[counter*3+2]=z*1.0f;

              colors[counter*4+0]=rr;colors[counter*4+1]=gg;colors[counter*4+2]=bb;colors[counter*4+3]=1.0f/*aa*/;  

              positions[counter*3+0]=x*r;positions[counter*3+1]=y*r;positions[counter*3+2]=z*r;
              counter++;
              s += ds;
            }

            t -= dt;
          }
/* first sphere end */
/* second sphere generation */
        {
            drho = 3.141593F / 32.0f;
            dtheta = 6.283186F / 32.0f;
            ds = 1.0F / 32.0f;
            dt = 1.0F / 32.0f;
            t = 1.0F;
            for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) {
                float rho = i * drho;

                float s = 0.0F;
                for (int j = 0; j <= 32; j++) {
                  float theta = j == 32 ? 0.0F : j * dtheta;
                  float x = (float) (-Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(rho));
                  float y = (float) (Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(rho));
                  float z = (float) (1.0f * Math.cos(rho));           
                 normals[counter*3+0]=x*1.0f;normals[counter*3+1]=y*1.0f;normals[counter*3+2]=z*1.0f;

                  colors[counter*4+0]=rr;colors[counter*4+1]=gg;colors[counter*4+2]=bb;colors[counter*4+3]=1.0f/*aa*/;  

                  positions[counter*3+0]=x*r+1.0f;positions[counter*3+1]=y*r+1.0f;positions[counter*3+2]=z*r+1.0f;
                  counter++;
                  x = (float) (-Math.sin(theta) * Math.sin(rho + drho));
                  y = (float) (Math.cos(theta) * Math.sin(rho + drho));
                  z = (float) (1.0f * Math.cos(rho + drho));

                  normals[counter*3+0]=x*1.0f;normals[counter*3+1]=y*1.0f;normals[counter*3+2]=z*1.0f;

                  colors[counter*4+0]=rr;colors[counter*4+1]=gg;colors[counter*4+2]=bb;colors[counter*4+3]=1.0f/*aa*/;  

                  positions[counter*3+0]=x*r+1.0f;positions[counter*3+1]=y*r+1.0f;positions[counter*3+2]=z*r+1.0f;
                  counter++;
                  s += ds;
                }

                t -= dt;
              }
        }
        /*second sphere end*/

        positionsBuf=BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(c1 * (c2+1) * 3*2  *2);
        positionsBuf.put(positions);
        positionsBuf.rewind();
        colorsBuf=BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(c1 * (c2+1) * 4*2  *2);
        colorsBuf.put(colors);
        colorsBuf.rewind();
        normalsBuf=BufferUtils.createFloatBuffer(c1 * (c2+1) * 3*2  *2);
        normalsBuf.put(normals);
        normalsBuf.rewind();
```

As you can see, below image shows how two spheres are drawn. There is an unwanted link between two.

[image: here]

Most probably the rope is caused by the last point of first sphere and first point of second sphere. Is there some kind of delimiter/drawing-hint to separate two drawings in the same buffer?

Here is how they are drawn:

```
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,sphereBufferCol.get(0));
         GL11.glColorPointer(4, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereBufferPos.get(0));
         GL11.glVertexPointer(3, GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, sphereBufferNormal.get(0));
         GL11.glNormalPointer(GL11.GL_FLOAT, 0, 0);



         GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
         GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
         GL11.glEnableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

         //Each sphere is generated 32 by 32 quadstriparray and each having two sets of two points and there are two spheres 
         GL11.glDrawArrays(GL11.GL_QUAD_STRIP, 0, 32*33*2 *2);



         GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
         GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_COLOR_ARRAY);
         GL11.glDisableClientState(GL11.GL_NORMAL_ARRAY);

         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
         GL15.glBindBuffer(GL15.GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, 0);
```

**Question:** How can I make that rope-like thing disappear without decreasing performance? Maybe putting zero to last and first points' alpha value can make it invisible but wouldnt that cause two holes on each sphere and decrease performance because of many lines on the screen?

All vertex values will be altered by opencl interoperability so single drawing call is needed to draw whole 10000+ spheres.

Comment: Is the code you posted above the GLU method or your own code? I don't see the call to `Sphere()`.

Comment: I copied the code from GLU.Sphere() and changed the contents to fit my buffer-generating method so nothing is wrong with creating a single sphere.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There seem to be a number of options:

- use multiple buffers
- use quads instead of quad strips
- use [primitive restart](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Primitive_Restart)
- use degenerate triangles, i.e. add the last vertex twice
- use [instanced rendering] (http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Vertex_Rendering#Instancing)

If you are on newer hardware and want to use quad strips, I'd prefer using primitive restart.

Please note that this is just the result of a quick assessment and anchecked (I personally don't use quad strips or even tri strips that often ;) ).

Comment: Okay, Im reading the primitive restart now. Device is HD7870.

Comment: Since Im not using element arrays(dont know how to use yet) Im looking  for glMultiDrawArrays but cannot find that. Which version of opengl needed for this?

Comment: Probably instanced rendering is missing  ;)

Comment: Changing quadstrip to quad needs extra coordinates, makes slower?

Comment: @MichaelIV I'll add it ;)

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik it might be somewhat slower, but I doubt you'll notice that. From the documention on opengl.org: "glMultiDrawArrays is available only if the GL version is 1.4 or greater."

Comment: @Tomas GL14.glMultiDrawArrays() will solve my problem. Thank you very very much. I'll use instancing when Im advanced.

Comment: Just found out that glMultiDrawArrays needs similar things like instanced version. I wish there was a similar version of primitive restart of elementarray one.

Comment: @huseyintugrulbuyukisik It is "slower" because you cannot benefit from post-T&L cache when no vertices are shared. In other words, the vertex shader has to calculate every vertex individually and cannot reuse the results of previous identical vertices. This is where indexed rendering and/or strip/fan primitives help with performance.